# Can we blacklist the "blender" tag immediately?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Following the lead of Caleb on Christianity.SE, [who requested that the tags "christianity" and "christian" be blacklisted six days into the private beta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/can-we-blacklist-the-christianity-tag), **I recommend that the tag [blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender) be blacklisted**. As we are on a site about Blender, having such a tag adds no value to any question because any on-topic question will be about Blender.

Comment: +1 see my answer here. http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/10/12

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should be the version tags?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-should-be-the-version-tags)

Comment: How about the [tag:3d] and the [tag:open-source] tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should already be a `^blender$` intrinsic tag blacklist. All sites (betas, at any rate) have this.

[image]

Comment: On the bicycles.SE site, you can use 'bicycles' as a tag (though your post will immediately get edited/deleted).

Answer (score 6):

I agree that the [blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender) tag should be blacklisted. Could we also look into blacklisting other tags that are inherent with the use of Blender, such as [graphics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics)?

Comment: +1 I think it makes a lot of sense to blacklist it, if all questions can fit under the `blender` tag then why have the tag at all?

Comment: You're not always asking about graphics...

Comment: to expand on @JNF's point: the [tag:scripting] and [tag:python] tags have little if anything to do with graphics.

Answer (score 5):

How about the [3d](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d) and the [open-source](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) tag?